# Using Bcrypt with Codeigniter login

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, bcrypt

I have a problem with logging in with code igniter using Bcrypt.
The password is hashed in my database. I have retrieved the hashed password from my database successfully but I can't seem to finish the validation.

Retrieving the hashed password:

```
 function getPass($username)
{
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->from("users");
    $this->db->where("username",$username);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        return $row->password;
    }
    }
}
```

My validate function is where I am trying to check the hashed password against the original:

```
 public function validate($hashedpass,$password)
    {

   $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username', true));

if ($this->bcrypt->check_password($password,$hashedpass)) { 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

And my controller:

```
     public function process()
    {

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $hashedpass = $this->login_model->getPass($username);
 $query = $this->login_model->validate($password,$username,$hashedpass);


        if($query){
            // If there is a user, then create session data and login etc..
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong in my validate function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies in your check_password function, which you do not show. Also, consider using an existing CodeIgniter library such as https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Added info to answer comment as this was too long for a comment:

It includes bcrypt as an available encryption library. The plugin was made several years ago and I believe that bcrypt is not the default, as it was not universally supported at the time, but it includes very simple instructions on how to make it the default.

It is a very plug and play library, takes minutes to implement, also has user groups for grouped permission sets, and has functions to drop into your controllers and check if they are authorized to use the particular page/permission being requested.

It also includes an admin GUI, with simple pages to manage users and groups, and it has a few front end pages, such as login, forgot password, etc.

It was built by CodeIgniter lovers for CodeIgniter lovers! It is fully 3.0 compatible, I use it on many projects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @colonelclick .. The check_password function is built into the bcrypt library already I'm just calling it.. Any other ideas as to what might be wrong?.. also, is the Ion-Auth as secure as Bcrypt?

Comment: Updated answer with info about your question, and suggested another answer as well.

Comment: Yes, Ion-Auth is as secure as bcrypt because it uses the bcrypt library.

Answer (score 0):

I did notice that your call to validate has 3 parameters

```
$query = $this->login_model->validate($password,$username,$hashedpass);
```

But your prototype has only two

```
public function validate($hashedpass,$password)
```

And this line appears unused...

```
$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username', true));
```